# How to Set textarea rows number from dataBase in Gridview use Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, gridview

in Gridview  columns I have textarea when I try to set textarea Rows number from data row is don’t work
I try:

```
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <textarea class="form-control pt-0 pb-0 pl-1 pr-1" rows="myFunction(<%# Eval("qustionText").ToString() %>)" wrap="soft"><%# Eval("qustionText") %></textarea>                                
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

my javascript code in end of page is:

```
<script>
  function myFunction(xVal) {
  var rows = xVal.split("\n");
  return rows.length;
 };
</script>
```

thanks.

Comment: Instead of adding as a function, you can set the length on page load by jquery by finding the text area using jquery. Have you tried to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the rows attribute of your textarea on page load.

```
        var grdvw = document.getElementById('<%= grdView.ClientID %>');
        for (var rowId = 1; rowId < grdvw.rows.length; rowId++) {
            var txtarea = grdvw.rows[rowId].cells[0].children[0];
            var rows = txtarea.value;
            rows = rows.split("\n");
            txtarea.setAttribute("rows",rows.length);
        }
```